# Show Only Posts Owned By Logged In User + my post

Tags: query-posts, get-posts

I would like to restrict access for logged in users to specific posts: their own posts and my posts (as they will serve as templates for them).

I find this code snippet that works perfectly to show them their own posts, but I would like them to be able to see my posts as well. Do you have any idea how I can do that? how I can update this code to make it work as I wish?

Many thanks in advance for your help. That will be much appreciated... ;-)

---

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'query_set_only_author' );

function query_set_only_author( $wp_query ) {
 global $current_user;
 if( is_admin() && !current_user_can('edit_others_posts') ) {
    $wp_query->set( 'author', $current_user->ID );
    add_filter('views_edit-post', 'fix_post_counts');
    add_filter('views_upload', 'fix_media_counts');
 }
}
```

---

Comment: This is a good read to resolve a big issue in your code / concept - https://tommcfarlin.com/pre_get_posts-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

First, I second Q Studio comment: check [Tom McFarlin's post](https://tommcfarlin.com/pre_get_posts-in-wordpress/) with a warning about using pre_get_posts. More specifically, `pre_get_posts` works everywhere, including RSS and dashboard, and you might want to exclude your logic from such places.

That said, if I understood correctly what you are trying to do, you can achieve it by using `author__in` parameter of [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#parameters) in [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/).

In fact, the developer documentation have an example:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'author__in' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );
```

Your code could be adapted like this:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse_382339_query_set_only_author' );

function wpse_382339_query_set_only_author( $wp_query ) {
    global $current_user;
    if( is_admin() && !current_user_can('edit_others_posts') ) {
    // 2 is just a placeholder for your user.
        $wp_query->set( 'author__in' , array( 2, $current_user->ID ) );
        add_filter('views_edit-post', 'fix_post_counts');
        add_filter('views_upload', 'fix_media_counts');
    }
}
```

Bear in mind that this allow users to SEE both their posts and yours. But not edit.

Let me know if it helps or you need more clarification